# tableview scrolling get the wrong last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to recreate facebook setting page

This is what facebook setting page looks like:

https://gfycat.com/SizzlingSorrowfulGrayfox

I have started a new project, using only 1 tableview, with style grouped, sections and with header.

I want to round each sections of the tableview. I have to round the top left and top right of the header (top part of the section), and bottom left and bottom right of the last cell (bottom part of the section).

I have done the top part, using below code in `HeaderTableViewCell`:

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.frame
rectShape.position = self.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
self.layer.mask = rectShape
```

**However when I do the same for the last cell, weird thing happen.**

https://gfycat.com/UnselfishCommonFlee

**When the page first loaded, the corners are correctly rounded, but however when I scroll down, and up, the second last cell got rounded.**

This is my code to round the last cell in `cellForRowAt`:

```
if indexPath.row + 1 == childArray?.count { //last cell, set corner radius

    print("is last cell")
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = rowDataCell.frame
    rectShape.position = rowDataCell.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rowDataCell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
    rowDataCell.layer.mask = rectShape
}else{
    rowDataCell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
}
```

Any help?

Comment: what's kind of rowDataCell? is it UITableViewCell or custom class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cell are reused. Any property you conditionally set must be reset.

You set the layer's `mask` for the last cell but you don't clear that mask when the cell isn't the last cell.

```
if indexPath.row + 1 == childArray?.count { //last cell, set corner radius
    print("is last cell")
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = rowDataCell.frame
    rectShape.position = rowDataCell.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rowDataCell.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
    rowDataCell.layer.mask = rectShape
}else{
    rowDataCell.layer.mask = nil
}
```

Comment: Hi. one more question. My last cell height seems to be a bit shorter than other cells, i suppose it is because i set the mask to nil. [see this](https://gfycat.com/YellowAnimatedBluetickcoonhound). but once scrolled down and up, the cell becomes normal. anyway to fix this?

Comment: Do some debugging and see what the original mask is before setting it.

Comment: all the masks are nil

Answer (score 0):

here is an easy way to solve this problem only add this line of code at the end of table view cell
rowDataCell.layer.mask = nil